# Springer Nature: use multiple references

Tags: bibtex, citing, sorting, springernature

[Here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support) is the Springer Nature template. I can't add multiple references in this format: `[1-4]`; instead it is adding references as `[1,2,3,4]`. Here is my reference code.

```
\cite{de_florio_physics-informed_2022,de_florio_physics-informed_2022-1,aliakbari_predicting_2022,abueidda_enhanced_2022}
```

and here is the output.

[image]

If I include `\usepackage{cite}` I get lots of errors in the document.

**ADDING ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**:

I am adding the whole preamble.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\jyear{2022}%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\raggedbottom
```

I didn't modify anything in `sn-basic.bst`

Comment: Please tell us which document class options you employ.

Comment: its `\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}`

Comment: Umm, the `sn-basic` class option tells LaTeX to load the `natbib` citation management package with the `authoryear` option, which tells LaTeX to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. Put differently, with the `sn-basic` option in effect, there's no way LaTeX will generate numeric-style citation call-outs *unless* your document contains some code -- about which you have so far not revealed any details -- that overrides the defaults and institutes numeric-style citation call-outs instead. Please do share these essential details with us. The macro name to look for may be `\setcitestyle`.

Comment: Hi I have added the preamble. I could find `\setcitestyle` in the main tex file or in the `sn-basic.bst` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've shown in your query does *not* generate numeric-style citation call-outs. Instead, it generates authoryear-style citation call-outs. I can only surmise that your document contains additional code -- possibly invoking the macros `\setcitestyle` and/or `\biboptions`. Not being blessed (cursed??) with any usable psychic divination powers, I can't and won't speculate on what this additional code may be.

What I do know, though, is that if you (a) specify `sort&compress` as an additional document class option and (b) add the directive

```
\setcitestyle{numbers,square,citesep={,}}
```

in the preamble, your document *will* generate sorted and compressed numeric-style citation call-outs.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic,sort&compress]{sn-jnl} %% 'sort&compress' is new 

%% create a sample bib file with four dummy entries:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{de_florio_physics-informed_2022,author={A},title={Eee},year=3001} 
@misc{de_florio_physics-informed_2022-1,author={B},title={Fff},year=3002} 
@misc{aliakbari_predicting_2022,author={C},title={Ggg},year=3003} 
@misc{abueidda_enhanced_2022,author={D},title={Hhh},year=3004} 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\jyear{2022}%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\raggedbottom

\setcitestyle{numbers,square,citesep={,}} %% <-- new

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{de_florio_physics-informed_2022,
       aliakbari_predicting_2022,
       de_florio_physics-informed_2022-1,
       abueidda_enhanced_2022}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```